# Is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(in)}{e^n}}$ convergent?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**PROBLEM**

Determine whether the following series is convergent or divergent, and find its sum if it is convergent.

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(in)}{e^n}}$$

**MY FIRST ATTEMPT**

Since $\cos(in) + i\sin(in) = e^{i(in)} = e^{-n}$, then 
$$\cos(-in) + i\sin(-in) = e^{i(-in)} = e^n,$$
so that
$$\cos(in) - i\sin(in) = e^n.$$
Consequently,
$$\sin(in) = \frac{e^{-n} - e^n}{2i}.$$
In particular,
$$\frac{\sin(in)}{e^n} = \frac{e^{-n} - e^n}{{2i}{e^n}} = \frac{e^{-2n} - 1}{2i}.$$
Therefore, we have
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(in)}{e^n}} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{e^{-2n} - 1}{2i}\bigg)} = \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\bigg(e^{-2n} - 1\bigg)} \to -\infty.$$

We conclude that the series is divergent.

**MY SECOND ATTEMPT**

Since $\cos(in) + i\sin(in) = e^{i(in)} = e^{-n}$, and because $e^{-n} \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$0 = \Im(e^{i(in)}) = \Im(e^{-n}) = \sin(in),$$
where $\Im(z)$ denotes the *imaginary part* of $z \in \mathbb{C}$.  Consequently,
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\sin(in)}{e^n}} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{0}{e^n}} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{0} = 0.$$
We therefore conclude that the series is convergent, and its sum is zero.

**QUESTION**

> Which of my two attempts above is correct?  (*Note that we have not covered the complex sine function yet.*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, the first approach is very correct.

Considering 
$$S_p=\sum_{n=2}^{p}{\frac{\sin(in)}{e^n}}=i\sum_{n=2}^{p}{\frac{\sinh(n)}{e^n}}=\frac i2\sum_{n=2}^{p}{\frac{e^n-e^{-n}}{e^n}}=\frac i2\sum_{n=2}^{p}(1-e^{-2n})$$ that is to say $$S_p=\frac i2\left(p-1+\frac{\frac{1}{e^2}-e^{-2 p}}{1-e^2} \right)$$ and, when $p$ becomes large $$S_p\sim \frac i2\left(p-1-\frac{1}{e^2(e^2-1)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is correct. Although you might want to make your algebra manipulation shorter but explain more the last step.

Your second attempt is incorrect:

> Since $\cos(in) + i\sin(in) = e^{i(in)} = e^{-n}$, and because $e^{-n} \in \mathbb{R}$, then
>   $$0 = \Im(e^{i(in)}) = \Im(e^{-n}) = \sin(in),$$
>   where $\Im(z)$ denotes the *imaginary part* of $z \in \mathbb{C}$. `(This is incorrect: to say` $\Im(x+iy)=y$ `in general, one must have that` $x,y\in{\bf R}$`. Your proof breaks down here.)`